# Run python app as admin without prompting for admin page

Tags: python, python-3.x, elevated-privileges, admin-rights

Can we run python app as admin by storing the admin credentials in python code and when python app needs admin rights it should use the admin credentials stored in it's code and run with admin rights. But it should not prompt for admin page.

Let the admin credentials be
Username:  admin
pass:      admin@123

Comment: Which operating system? Anyway, the best way to handle this is outside the program you are running, which means, there will be some runner, which performs the elevation of the privileged, and then starts your program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the os is Windows(10)

Comment: Thank you, and I will try with your concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I successfully used on WinXP and Win7 and I see no
reason why it should not work on Win10.

```
global userH
userH = None
def try_login(name, domain, password):
    global userH
    try:
        logging.info("Trying to login as: %s/%s" % (domain, name))
        userH = win32security.LogonUser(name, domain, password,
                win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
        if None!=userH:
            win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(userH)
            logging.info("Logged in: %s/%s" % (domain, name))
            return True
    except:
        logging.exception("Windows login")
        if userH:
            try:
                win32api.CloseHandle(userH)
            except:
                pass
        userH = None
    return False

def logout():
    if userH:
        try:
            win32security.RevertToSelf()
            win32api.CloseHandle(userH)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. It works great in windows 10 also. Can we perform any admin activities by logging with admin credentials?